# How to find file type in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to find information about a file I downloaded from a link using `NSURLSession` and I don't know how to find out if it's an image/video or whatever. I am looking for a function call that is similar to the command line tool `file` to give information about that file.

Any ideas would be helpful :)

Comment: Can you look at the extension of the file in the url? If you can read the file extension, you should only need to then determine the file type with a series of if conditions.

Comment: No, not really. The file has no extension so it is not straightforward to find out.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know the file type of a resource that you requested over HTTP you should take a look at the `content-type` header in the HTTP response. The server returns a `MIME` type that describes the file type.

You can find a list of common media types [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#List_of_common_media_types).

Using the `content-type` header is mostly more reliable than looking at a file ending.

You can use the `allHeaderFields` property of `NSHTTPURLResponse` to access the response headers ([Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPURLResponse_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSHTTPURLResponse/allHeaderFields)).

Comment: I forgot to mention that I was working with _Download Tasks_ and I managed to get the server response in an easier way with `downloadTask.response` within `didFinishDownloadingToURL`

Comment: downloadTask.response?.MIMEType